# Compilation error with lambda capturing templated parameters

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, lambda, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to pass template arguments to a function on an object when the object type is a template argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512224/is-there-a-way-to-pass-template-arguments-to-a-function-on-an-object-when-the-ob)

I have been learning how to use lambdas in C++ lately when I came across the following problem.

When I write a lambda which captures a templated variable (by reference or by copy, doesn't matter), I get a weird compilation error, not related to the lambda itself. The test code is as follows:

```
// templated.cpp  
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T, class Function>
Function for_each_index(const T& v, Function f)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { f(i); }
    return f;
}

class Test
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T f() { return 1; }
};

template<class T>
void fun(T& v)
{
    for_each_index(v, [&v] (unsigned int i) {
        v[i].f<float>();
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> v;
    v.push_back(Test());
    v.push_back(Test());
    v.push_back(Test());
    fun(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation of the above code fails with the following message:

```
$ g++ -Wall templated.cpp -std=c++0x
templated.cpp: In lambda function:
templated.cpp:23:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
templated.cpp:23:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘float’
```

However, if I move the lambda to `main` (no template there), it compiles just fine:

```
// simple.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T, class Function>
Function for_each_index(const T& v, Function f)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { f(i); }
    return f;
}

class Test
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T f() { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Test> v;
    v.push_back(Test());
    v.push_back(Test());
    v.push_back(Test());
    for_each_index(v, [&v] (unsigned int i) {
        v[i].f<float>();
    });
    return 0;
}
```

I use `for_each_index` here as I am using a similar "iterating tool" in my own code, from which the above error comes from (the original code does some heavy image processing, this code is a proof of concept). However, it servers a second purpose here - to avoid putting templated variable in lambda arguments.

So, is this a compiler bug? Or am I doing something very wrong? If so, what possible workaround could you suggest?

FYI, I am using a standard Ubuntu-issue `g++`, version `4.6.3`.

Comment: Try `v[i].template f<float>();`. If that works then read this FAQ: [What is the `->template`, `.template` and `::template` syntax about?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#templateprefix).

Comment: Thank you, sir! It worked like a charm. And the link you provided is a good read. Voting to close as the question is misleading - it's not a lambda problem _per se_.